# WPF TextBox detect if mouse is over text

Tags: wpf, textbox, mouseover

Is there a way to detect if Mouse is over the actual text of the TextBox - not over the whole control?

Something like "OnMouseOverContent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, no i don't think so, but what could work is to use MouseOver, and then calculate that yourself via [GetCharacterIndexFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getcharacterindexfrompoint.aspx) using the mouse position. If the index is not -1 you are propably over the text content.